# Does C internally use Karatsuba algorithm to multiply two integers?

Tags: c, algorithm, multiplication

When C multiplies two `n-bits` integers, does it internally use the normal `O(n^2)` multiplication algorithm, or does it use a variation of Karatsuba's `O(n^log_2(3))` multiplication algorithm ?

Comment: The C standard doesn't itself dictate such implementation details. Each compiler chooses appropriate instructions per target architecture, so it will depend on that instruction set.

Comment: C - no. Compiler - probably not. Underlying HW architecture - maybe.

Comment: C doesn't have n-bits integers.

Comment: @StoryTeller I see, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is implementation dependent. On hardware that doesn't have multiplication instructions, probably yes, but you need to check the source code of the libraries/compiler.

Comment: @barakmanos Its neither H.W nor am I taking an architecture course. I am taking an algorithms course and I was just curious to know.

Comment: @melpomene - What's `int_least8_t` to `int_least64_t`  then? :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Fixed-width integers. :-) I interpret `n` to mean a variable or arbitrary amount of bits, as in gmp or similar.

Comment: "Its neither H.W nor am I taking an architecture course"? What does that have to do with what I said???

Comment: @barakmanos  I interpreted "Underlying HW architecture - maybe" as you saying that this is perhaps a computer architecture course HW. My apologies if that wasn't what you meant, English is not my first language :).

Comment: @user3508551: Neither is it mine :)

Comment: The value of `n` is known at compile time. A good optimizing compiler will use the most efficient algorithm for that value of `n` on the target architecture.

Comment: if n <= bit width of the architecture then no

Comment: @user3508551 HW means hardware not homework

Answer (score 4):

No. The 'book-keeping' overhead of the Karatsuba algorithm is too high and too complex. It would take up far more silicon than a multiplier, even if it was to achieve a break-even recursive depth on a machine word level. A hardware crypto accelerator or FPGA might make it worthwhile for large enough `n`. Even then, the break-even might be too high to be useful for crypto needs. There's no free lunch.

On the other end of the spectrum, we can look at the `gmp-mparam.h` files in the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/), which define *threshold* values at which asymptotically faster algorithms actually begin to pay off. 'Karatsuba' is the 2x2 case of the more general Toom-Cook algorithm. Even on monsters like Broadwell and Skylake CPUs, the threshold is around 28 'words', or 1792 bits. That's due to the overhead in (recursively) adding 3 results back together, with carry propagation. These thresholds will keep getting higher as multiply instruction throughput increases.

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't multiply. It defines the semantics of the binary `*` operator. How it's implemented is left to the compiler.

The compiler doesn't multiply. It converts the binary `*` operator into (a) machine instruction(s), which are executed by the CPU.

The CPU multiplies. It generally provides specialized instructions for that. What instructions it offers to the compiler, and how it implements these instructions depends on the CPU and it's intended use. But multiplication is such a common task that any desktop CPU worth it's salt has dedicated hardware circuitry for it.